# How to P\Invoke RegOpenKeyExW, RegEnumKeyW and RegQueryValueEx in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, registry, pinvoke

I am working on retrieval of applications installed in a system. However using Registry Keys I am able to get the details of applications whose keys are in HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall but I am unable to retrieve the details from HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. I am using same function for both the Registry directories. I am working on .NET 3.5 Framework and read somewhere that I need to P\Invoke RegOpenKeyExW but I have no idea how to proceed for it.

```
public static bool IsApplictionInstalled(string p_name)
{
    string keyName;

    // search in: CurrentUser
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // search in: LocalMachine_32
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // search in: LocalMachine_64
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static bool ExistsInSubKey(RegistryKey p_root, string p_subKeyName, string p_attributeName, string p_name)
{
    RegistryKey subkey;
    string displayName;

    using (RegistryKey key = p_root.OpenSubKey(p_subKeyName))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (string kn in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (subkey = key.OpenSubKey(kn))
                {
                    displayName = subkey.GetValue(p_attributeName) as string;
                    if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute your program as administrator? probably you don't have permission to access that registry path

Comment: @Gusman I tried using administrator also, still same problem!

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried to use Regedit to check if there is any problem in your registry? Also, have you tried to compile it as a 64 bit executable? (Wow6432Node is for 32 bit apps, without Wow6432Node it's the registry for 64 bit apps, maybe if your app is 32 bits you can't access those keys)

Comment: @Gusman I have checked Registry, there is no problem. On compiling as 64 bit also nothing happened.

Comment: Saying "nothing happened" is not helpful. The registry redirector has behaviour that is well known. Your code will be wrong but you didn't show it. You need to spend time reading the docs. Don't try to do the is c# without first learning it in c++. Insane to do that. By far the simplest approach is to use .net 4 and RegistryView.